# Manjaro / SDDM Login during typing

Tags: login, manjaro, sddm

i have a strange but super annoying problem. Every time i start my pc i go to the login screen and start typing my password. In the middle of typing, i get the message "Login failed". So somehow it logs me in without pressing enter or clicking the login button.

It really drives me crazy. Not sure where to search for errors to be honest.
Today i even locked me out and had to open a console with root to unlock my account again...

Comment: Can you look at your auth logs and see if it is somehow getting multiple logins or failures? e.g. can you narrow it down to "it thinks I am typing"?

Comment: I can definitely see the errors in my logs. It happens only when i login within the UI, never happens in the console. I changed all kind of login screens already, but the behaviour is every time the same.
Computer start, i see the login, i start typing and while i do that, it tries to log me in... so strange